# Angularjs provider: How to pass options to or config a provider from a controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I pass options to or config a provider **from a controller**?

Here is a provider example that I pass options/ config inside the provider js file,

provider.js,

```
app.provider('contactProvider', function() {
        this.name = 'Default';
        this.$get = ['$rootScope','$route','$http', function($rootScope,$route,$http) {

            var name = this.name;
            return {
                sayHello: function() {
                    return "Hello, " + name + "! From Provider!!"
                }
            }
          }];

        this.setName = function(name) {
            this.name = name;
        };
    });

    app.config(function(contactProviderProvider){
        contactProviderProvider.setName('World');
    });
```

controller.js,

```
app.controller("ListContacts", function($scope,contactProvider){

        console.log(contactProvider.sayHello());

    });
```

result,

```
Hello, World! From Provider!!
```

Here is a provider example that I pass options/ config **inside the controller js file**,

provider.js,

```
app.provider('contactProvider', function() {
        this.name = 'Default';
        this.$get = ['$rootScope','$route','$http', function($rootScope,$route,$http) {

            var name = this.name;
            return {
                sayHello: function() {
                    return "Hello, " + name + "! From Provider!!"
                }
            }
          }];

        this.setName = function(name) {
            this.name = name;
        };
    });
```

controller.js,

```
app.config(function(contactProviderProvider){
            contactProviderProvider.setName('World');
        });

app.controller("ListContacts", function($scope,contactProvider){

        console.log(contactProvider.sayHello());

    });
```

result,

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: contactProviderProvider http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/unpr?p0=contactProviderProvider minErr/<@http://localhost/test/2013/php-angular/2013/12/1-requirejs/js/lib/angular/angular.js:78
```

but sometimes I get the result correctly (how come!??),

```
Hello, World! From Provider!!
```

What should I do to pass the options from outside the provider js file **correctly** then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the error because your `controller.js` file is loaded before `provider.js`;
When the `provider.js` is cached you get the true result.
you can use `require.js` for handling this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is caused by requirejs and it seems to be fixed by this,

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'app',
    'factory/factoryContacts'
], function ($,app) {

  app.config(function (contactProvider) {
    contactProvider.setName('World 8');
  });

    app.controller("ListContacts", function($scope,contact){
        //contact.setName('World 8');
        console.log(contact.sayHello());

    });
....
```

It is odd and what a hack!